# Function prototypes without argument name and function declaration without data type in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function-prototypes

Good afternoon,

I've been tasked with implementing code that seems to have been written for C99 in Visual Studio 2010. I've researched numerous C99/Visual Studio compatibility threads, but I haven't found anything relating to fixing my issue.

Basically, the code I have to port has function prototype and declaration written in the following way:

```
void myfunc(int, char*); //Prototype

void myfunc(variable1, pointer1) //Declaration
{
   ;//...
}
```

But Visual Studio 2010 is only willing to accept

```
void myfunc(int variable1, char* pointer1); //Prototype

void myfunc(int variable1, char* pointer1) //Declaration
{
   ;//...
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is even a C99 compatibility issue or some outdated coding practice, but the source file is being constatly updated by a third party and it's a requirement for me to avoid changing anything in it (such as renaming each single function), it is also a requirement for me to use visual studio 2010 because of a plug-in compiler. Is there an option that may allow this style of function declarations?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know MS VC++ does not support C99.

As for the function definition thsi definition

```
void myfunc(variable1, pointer1) //Declaration
{
   ;//...
}
```

is invalid even for C89. After this header

```
void myfunc(variable1, pointer1)
```

and before the opening brace there shall be identifier declarations.
If these declarations are present and you made simply a typo then you can use MS VC++ 2010. But you have to compile the code as C code.

According to the C Standard

> 6 If the declarator includes an identifier list, each declaration in
>   the declaration list shall have at least one declarator, those
>   declarators shall declare only identifiers from the identifier list,
>   and every identifier in the identifier list shall be declared. An
>   identifier declared as a typedef name shall not be redeclared as a
>   parameter. The declarations in the declaration list shall contain no
>   storage-class specifier other than register and no initializations.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about is the old style C syntax. No, there are no identifier declarations. The code is supposed to compile under Eclipse in Linux otherwise.

Comment: @user2056201 I added a quote from the C Standard. It seems you have very old code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difference between C and C++.

In fact, in C++, please see my corrected annotations below:

```
void myfunc(int variable1, char* pointer1); // Declaration

void myfunc(int variable1, char* pointer1)  // Definition
{
   // ...
}
```